# How to sync remote with local copy

Tags: git

I have a repository on BitBucket and I would like for the master repository to be in sync with my local copy. Right now there's many files on remote that have been deleted locally but the changes have not been changed on the repository. How can I sync with remote repository with my local copy?

Comment: Question is unclear. You want remote to reflect changes you made on local, or local to become exactly the same as remote?

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` should work, or `git pull <remote name> <branch name>` if you have more than one remote and/or branch.

EDIT: Apologies, that would delete the same files that are missing in the repository from your working copy. As per the above, make sure all files in your working copy are added to version control, then `git commit` then `git push` should sort it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to commit the changes, i.e. the deleted files:

```
git add -A .
git commit
```

Then you can push your changes to the remote.

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

`<remote>` might be `origin` and `<branch>` could be `master`.

To get changes made on a remote use `git pull` as in orbrey's answer or `git fetch` + `git reset` as in o11c's answer. Be aware that information might get lost when using `git reset`.

You can find documentation on [git's website](http://git-scm.com/doc). Here are the links for the mentioned commands:

- [git-add](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)
- [git-commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)
- [git-push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)
- [git-pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
- [git-fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)
- [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly make local a copy of remote, even in the case of rebases or local changes:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

We use this on CI and interactive testing servers; just `git pull` will fail in many ways.